# Change MySQL stored procedure 'Database Collation' name

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I have imported a DB from Local machine to server machine. While importing the Database, the character set values of the DB are set by system default to "Latin". I have changed the character set to "`utf8`" for the Database. But, the stored procedure of Database collation values are not modified. Currently it is "`latin1_swedish_ci`". How to change the Database collation values from "`latin1_swedish_ci`" to "`utf8_general_ci`" for all the stored procedures.

```
SELECT DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME, DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = DB_Name;

USE DB_Name;
ALTER DATABASE DB_Name
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
DEFAULT COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

SET NAMES UTF8;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One option is DROP PROCEDURE and CREATE PROCEDURE. Another option (less recommended) can be manually update the `db_collation` column of the table `proc` of the database `mysql`. The ideal is to properly configure your MySQL server and then do the import.

Comment: Can you run the import again? I'd try to solve this before the import. Its easier to specify a correct encoding before you start importing. Does your db dump contain SET NAMES command?

Comment: @olegsv Yes, you are correct. I solved this issue before importing the DB dump and dump contain with SET NAMES.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As documented under [CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-procedure.html) (emphasis added):

> If `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATE` attributes are not present, **the database character set and collation in effect at routine creation time are used**.   To avoid having the server use the database character set and collation, provide explicit `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATE` attributes for character data parameters.
>
> If you change the database default character set or collation, **stored routines that use the database defaults must be dropped and recreated** so that they use the new defaults.

Comment: The documentation doesn't really tell you how to use them. Also mysql workbench has a bug that tells you the COLLATE is always invalid, even when it is.

Comment: Just set  
``set @@local.collation_server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`` , ``set @@local.character_set_server = utf8mb4;`` right before creating the procedure/function.