# How can I solve "Collation is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'"?

Tags: mysql, rds

I know this question is asked a lot but since I've tried every answer I wanted to ask again with more detailed information.

I'm migrating data from a different database (different structured MySQL 5.6.34) to a MySQL 5.7.16

I'm getting the following error for different tries;

COLLATION 'utf8_unicode_ci/utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'

My parameter set is as

```
 character_set_client =>      utf8                                      
 character_set_connection =>  utf8                                      
 character_set_database =>    utf8                                      
 character_set_filesystem =>  binary                                    
 character_set_results =>     utf8                                      
 character_set_server =>      utf8                                      
 character_set_system =>      utf8                                     
 collation_connection =>  utf8_general_ci   
 collation_database =>    utf8_general_ci   
 collation_server =>      utf8_unicode_ci
```

Also the two tables are set to utf8 and utf_general_ci respectively.

Here is the insert query;

```
INSERT INTO t1 (detail)SELECT null_if_empty(detail) COLLATE utf_general_ci FROM t2;
```

Here is the function used "null_if_empty"

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `null_if_empty`(value TEXT) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8

BEGIN DECLARE response_value TEXT DEFAULT NULL; IF (LENGTH(value) > 0) THEN
SET response_value = value; ELSE
SET response_value = NULL; END IF; RETURN response_value; END;
```

PS:Both databases are kept on AWS RDS.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem seems to arise from procedures (null_if_empty) collation and charset. Those were set to latin1 and latin1_swedish_ci. MySQL document says;

> If CHARACTER SET and COLLATE attributes are not present, the database character set and collation in effect at routine creation time are used. To avoid having the server use the database character set and collation, provide explicit CHARACTER SET and COLLATE attributes for character data parameters.
>
> If you change the database default character set or collation, stored
>   routines that use the database defaults must be dropped and recreated
>   so that they use the new defaults.

Also stated on this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35560779/1092406