# Why does MySQL CAST operate differently within a stored Function?

Tags: mysql, casting

I am trying to write a MySQL function that uses CAST, but I'm getting errors that do not appear when I execute the same cast statement outside of the function.

I have a table with numeric values that may also contain alpha characters.

```
mysql> select * from runway;
+-------------+
| base_end_id |
+-------------+
| 009         |
| 01          |
| 01C         |
| 01H         |
| 01L         |
| 01R         |
| 01W         |
| 02          |
| 02C         |
| 02H         |
| 02L         |
| 02R         |
| 02W         |
+-------------+
```

If I cast this to an integer, MySQL happily ignores the characters:

```
mysql> SELECT base_end_id, cast(base_end_id as SIGNED) from runway;
+-------------+-----------------------------+
| base_end_id | cast(base_end_id as SIGNED) |
+-------------+-----------------------------+
| 009         |                           9 |
| 01          |                           1 |
| 01C         |                           1 |
| 01H         |                           1 |
| 01L         |                           1 |
| 01R         |                           1 |
| 01W         |                           1 |
| 02          |                           2 |
| 02C         |                           2 |
| 02H         |                           2 |
| 02L         |                           2 |
| 02R         |                           2 |
| 02W         |                           2 |
+-------------+-----------------------------+
```

But if I do the same within a stored function, I get an error:

```
mysql> SELECT base_end_id, ConvertRunway(base_end_id) from runway;
ERROR 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '01C'
```

The ConvertRunway function is:

```sql
FUNCTION `ConvertRunway`(rwy varchar(10))
RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
RETURN cast(rwy as SIGNED);
END
```

How can I use CAST within my function?

Comment: The stored procedure has its own `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATE` attributes, which are different from the table.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34353072/change-mysql-stored-procedure-database-collation-name

Comment: @Barmar, is there a reason you posted as a comment and not an answer? Is this an answer, or just a guess?

Comment: Kind of a guess, but I think the linked question might be the solution.

Comment: @Barmar, I've set both my table and stored function to use latin1 and latin1_sweedish_ci. No change. As to this question being a duplicate... hardly a dupplicate question even if you think the solution may be the same as the linked question!